# What is the mouse shortcut for Windows 10 Task View on Parallels?

Tags: windows-10, parallels, task-view

I use Windows 10 in Parallels on a MacBook Pro.  A couple of times per day, I accidentally go into Task View while moving my mouse.  I can't seem to figure out what mouse gesture I'm doing to trigger this.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  As far as I can tell, Parallels interprets a swipe in from the left side of the trackpad as a swipe in from the left side of a touchscreen monitor, thus activating Task View.

[Image of task view swiping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/998Xr.jpg)

Comment: Is there a way to disable this? It seems to be tied to Virtual Desktops, but I have never added any of them, and I can't figure out how to disable that feature. I guess I tend to be on the left side of the trackpad, which triggers this "feature" a lot. I'd love to know how to strip this out.

Comment: Try this.  http://kb.parallels.com/en/123659